# How to create a background thread with a looper

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

Can someone please share the implementation of a background thread with a Looper that i can pass to the subscribeOn(AndroidScheduler.from(/*backgroundThreadWithLooper*/)).

I need this because i am trying to implement a DBService class that runs all of its operations in the background while still getting live objects updates. So when i apply an addChangeListener, an exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Your Realm is opened from a thread without a Looper. Async queries need a Handler to send results of your query
```

or if i use findAll() instead of findAllAsync():

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can't register a listener from a non-Looper thread or IntentService thread.
```

DBService code:

```
public Observable<List> getAll(Class clazz) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return realm.where(clazz).findAll().asObservable()
                .map(o -> realm.copyFromRealm((RealmResults) o))
                .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> closeRealm(realm))
                .doOnTerminate(() -> closeRealm(realm));
    });
}
```

Comment: see `HandlerThread`

Comment: @pskink thanks, that worked for me

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Kotlin Coroutines for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HandlerThread does the job.

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("backgroundThread");
if (!handlerThread.isAlive())
    handlerThread.start();
AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of Thread with Looper:

```java
public class GameLoop extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        Looper.prepare(); // at first write this line of code
        //do something
        Looper.loop(); //and at the end write this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me

```
public class MainScopeListener
        extends Fragment {
    Realm realm;

    HandlerThread handlerThread;

    Scheduler looperScheduler;

    Observable<Realm> realmObservable;

    Subscription realmSubscription;

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    public MainScopeListener() {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Injector.INSTANCE.initializeComponent(realm);
        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("REALM_LOOPER") {
            @Override
            protected void onLooperPrepared() {
                super.onLooperPrepared();
                Log.i(getName(), "ON LOOPER PREPARED");
                handler.post(() -> {
                    looperScheduler = AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper());
                    realmObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Realm>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super Realm> subscriber) {
                            final Realm observableRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                            observableRealm.setAutoRefresh(true);
                            final RealmChangeListener<Realm> listener = realm1 -> {
                                if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                                    subscriber.onNext(observableRealm);
                                }
                            };
                            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> {
                                observableRealm.removeChangeListener(listener);
                                observableRealm.setAutoRefresh(false);
                                observableRealm.close();
                            }));
                            observableRealm.addChangeListener(listener);

                            // Immediately call onNext with the current value, as due to Realm's auto-update, it will be the latest
                            // value.
                            subscriber.onNext(observableRealm);
                        }
                    });
                    realmSubscription = realmObservable.unsubscribeOn(looperScheduler).subscribeOn(looperScheduler).subscribe(realm12 -> {
                        Log.i("REALM SUBSCRIPTION", "An event occurred on background thread!");
                    });
                });
            }
        };
        handlerThread.start();
    }

    public void configureRealmHolder(MainActivity.RealmHolder realmHolder) {
        realmHolder.realm = this.realm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(realmSubscription != null && !realmSubscription.isUnsubscribed() ) {
            realmSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        handlerThread.quit();
        realm.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("NewApi")
private Subscription writePeriodic() {
    return Observable.interval(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //
            .takeWhile(aLong -> counter < DogNames.values().length) //
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(aLong -> {
                try(Realm bgRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                    bgRealm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
                        long currentIndex = realm1.where(Dog.class).max(Dog.Fields.ID.getField()).longValue();
                        Dog dog = new Dog();
                        dog.setId(currentIndex + 1);
                        dog.setName(DogNames.values()[((Long) dog.getId()).intValue() % DogNames.values().length].name());
                        dog = realm1.copyToRealmOrUpdate(dog);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Realm write successful [" + counter + "] :: [" + dog.getName() + "].");
                        counter++;
                    });
                }
            }).subscribe();
}
```

Results in

```
01-21 00:58:51.672 2094-2127/com.zhuinden.rxrealm I/DogView: Realm write successful [1] :: [Munch].
01-21 00:58:51.672 2094-2115/com.zhuinden.rxrealm I/REALM SUBSCRIPTION: An event occurred on background thread!
```

So the HandlerThread Realm is able to receive automatic updates.

Copying from the Realm still results in eager evaluation of results, so it is not an efficient way of handling large data sets.

Comment: I like your approach, but still this does not solve my problem of when to close the realm instance. I am doing my db operations in a class that is not exposed to the activity life cycle. So i open and close instances with every operation, which forces me to use copyFromRealm. I want to keep this pattern but i also want to have live updates. I will update my question with code.