# How can I solve the problem with the OnClick?

Tags: android, onclick

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: andoid.example.taxiluks, PID: 5627
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6320)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25087)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6749)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6320) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25087) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6749) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.EditText com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.getEditText()' on a null object reference
        at andoid.example.taxiluks.PassengerSingInActivity.validateEmail(PassengerSingInActivity.java:73)
        at andoid.example.taxiluks.PassengerSingInActivity.passengerCreateLogIn(PassengerSingInActivity.java:130)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6320) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25087) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:869) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6749) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
```

Comment: You should fix this Nullpointer: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.EditText com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.getEditText()' on a null object reference". Can you show us where you call `TextInputLayout.getEditText()`. Maybe you are accessing the view before inflation.

Comment: this question may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770875/how-to-create-a-background-thread-with-a-looper